# Logic to Divide IF-ELSE-ENDIF loop

Tags: java, algorithm, logic

This is my first question , please correct me if anything is wrong.
I have some set of old rules in one of document system , im trying to convert them into new document system.
I have lot of `IF-ENDIF` and `IF-ELSE-ENDIF` nested inside each other like below. Need some logic which works on converting below input to corresponding output.
Need help for algo. Thanks

```
INPUT:  
IF (Cond 1)  
    IF(Cond 2)  
    ENDIF  
    IF(Cond3)  
    ELSE  
    ENDIF  
ELSE  
    IF(Cond4)  
    ELSE  
        IF(Cond5)  
        ELSE  
        ENDIF  
    ENDIF  
    IF(Cond6)  
    ENDIF  
ENDIF
```

Required OUTPUT:

```
    IF(Cond1) AND (Cond2)  
    IF(Cond1) AND (Cond3)  
    IF(Cond1) AND !(Cond3)  
    IF!(Cond1) AND (Cond4)  
    IF!(Cond1) AND !(Cond4)  AND (Cond5)  
    IF!(Cond1) AND !(Cond4) AND !(Cond5)  
    IF!(Cond1) AND (Cond6)
```

Comment: how did you come up with the output ? apply the same logic in code...

Comment: i typed that ouput manually

Comment: So, you need to parse the input and generate the output from what was parsed?

Comment: yes , i initially tried removing else with not(!) of if condition, then combining if conditions , but doesn't work for all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that you have logic that can parse the file in the first place.  If so, then you should end up with an abstract syntax tree where each node looks something like this:

```
If
  |
  +--- Condition
  |
  +--- Positive statement
  |
  +--- Negative statement
```

or

```
Sequence
  |
  +--- Statement 1
  |
  +--- Statement 2
  |
  ...
  |
  +--- Statement n
```

or

```
Terminal
```

where Terminal represents a concrete statement.  They are implicit in your original input file.  For example, "IF(COND2) ENDIF" would be represented as follows:

```
If
  |
  +--- Cond2
  |
  +--- Terminal
  |
  +--- (null)
```

In your case, your actual tree would look something like this:

```
If
  |
  +--- Cond1
  |
  +--- Sequence
  |      |
  |      +--- If
  |      |      |
  |      |      +--- Cond2
  |      |      |
  |      |      +--- Terminal
  |      |      |
  |      |      +--- (null)
  |      |
  |      +--- If
  |             |
  |             +--- Cond3
  |             |
  |             +--- Terminal
  |             |
  |             +--- Terminal
  |
  +--- If
       ...
```

To generate the output, you would simply recursively walk down the tree, building a stack of conditions along the way, then when you get to a statement, output the whole stack of conditions with ANDs between them.  Here is some pseudocode:

```
void treeWalk(root):
    treeWalk(root, []);

void treeWalk(root, conditions):
    case root of:
        If(cond, positive, negative):
            if (positive is not null):
                treeWalk(positive, conditions + cond)
            if (negative is not null):
                treeWalk(negative, conditions + !cond)
        Sequence(statements):
            for each statement in statements:
                treeWalk(statements, conditions)
        Terminal:
            print "IF "
            for each condition in conditions:
                if (condition is not the last condition):
                    print " AND "
                print condition
```

Here I am using + to indicate appending an item to a list.  It is assumed that !cond results in a condition that prints itself out with a "!" at the front.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

assuming you read and parsed the input into a tree-like data structure where each node represents an 'if-else' statement and the children are the nested if-else statements, here's some rough pseudo code that should give you the general idea:

```
process(tree,output)
  if tree == null
    write output to file
    return
  for each child in body of if
     process(child,output + "AND <condition of root node in tree>")
  for each child in body of else
     process(child,output + "AND !<condition of root node in tree>")
```